# password validation questions

Tags: php

I am coding a registration system. I decided to encrypt the passwords and let the users use whatever they want in their passwords, including spaces.

The only restrictions would be:
- no spaces at the start or end of password
- min 5 char and max 30 characters

```
// CHECK PASSWORD    
    } elseif ((substr($password, 0, 1) == " " || substr($password, -1, 1) == " ")){ 
        $msg = "You cannot have a space in the beginning or end of your password.";

    } elseif (strlen($password) > 30)) {
        $msg = "Your password cannot be longer than 20 characters.";


    } elseif (strlen($password) < 5)) {
        $msg = "Your password cannot be shorter than 5 characters.";
```

Is that enough?

I'll also take this chance to ask how should I treat the password before and after encrypting it. Should I just encrypt it and then escape it?

Comment: Encrypt it for what?  Surely you mean a salted hash instead?

Comment: Why do you want to impose constraints on *where* certain characters are?  Or limit the length?  How does that help?

Comment: I can understand a minimum length password, but why impose a maximum?  Your error message on the length being over 30 characters is misleading - it says 20.  And I agree with Oli, why would you check where any character is in the password.

Comment: @Brad I'd run it through md5 with a salt. Whatever it's called.

Comment: @Oil Because users may type a space at the end of pass by accident. I've done it. A minimum length is surely needed. How secure would a one character password be? I figured a maximum length should also be in place since it didn't make much sense that the password can be longer than the hash. I didn't bother to look it up though and I assume now that I was wrong?

Comment: @domino, don't use MD5, use whirlpool with a different salt for each password.

Comment: @domino: The user might type *any* character at the end by accident...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is not encryption, but hashing. A hash algorythm takes some arbitrary value and tranforms it into a fixed-size string. It's well suited for this becouse a hash algorythm is one-way, i.e. you can hash something but you can't unhash it.

For more security, you can add a 'salt' to avoid rainbow tables. A rainbow table is a table with already-calculated hashes for known words. For example  a user has a password of "apple" wich produces the hash "XABC". If a hacker has the hash"XABC", he goes to a rainbow table and looks for a word that produces the hash "XABC". Since apple is a common word, so is it's hash and it will probably be in the table. The salt avoids this since it added before the the hashing occurs. you just concatenate it to the string to be hashed. So if the user uses the password "apple", your script doesn't hash apple, it hashes "saltedapple" wich no loger produces the known hash "XABC". 'saltedapple' is not a known word and its less likely to be in a rainbow table. 'salted' is a pretty simple salt, but using '$ZX?(' would make '$ZX?(apple' wich i can asure you that's not in any rainbow table.

Comment: This is one reason for using a salt, but is perhaps the weakest; if the attacker already has access to the hashed passwords, then they have access to your database, which means you're already screwed.

Comment: I understand hashing, I just had the terminology mixed. I'm still confused about the maximum length. I must still limit it somehow, right?

Comment: salt, isn't a panacea! if you'd like to use strong algorithm use `mcrypt` and read this article - http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: @domino The hash generated will be the same length no matter the length of the plain text password. The hash generated by `sha1("");` is 40 characters long, as is the `sha1` of the entire contents of the bible.

Comment: @adlawson Ah yes, it's one way. Makes more sense now. So I will probably go with no limits and sha1. Salt shall be md5 of the email or username.. Or both. Should I run mysql_real_escape_string(); after or before hashing?

Comment: @domino there is no need for ´mysql_real_escape_string()´ as the sql injected would be hashed before it goes to the db. Anyway, just in case, you couls use ´filter_var´ with the ´FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING´ filter.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of check for spaces in begin and and of string, you can just `trim($password)`

You don't need to encrypt password at all. Just encrypt it with something like

```
function encryptPassword($enteredPassword) {
   return md5(sha1($enteredPassword);
}
```

and validate user entered password, after encryption, with same stored password;

p.s. it is much better to use mcrypt, with more difficult algorithm.

Comment: MD5 and SHA1 are not encryption, they are hashes.  Furthermore, why would you ever do both like this?  You aren't helping anything here.  Finally, don't `trim()` a password... I'd be really confused if my password started or ended with a space that you ignored.  I wouldn't be able to login later!

Comment: What if the user typed the space intentionally and I trim it without notifying?

Comment: if you always will trim a space, user won't notice it; when  you don't trim, many of your users wouldn't be able to login, for example if they copy a password from mail, and by mistake copy it with one more space...

Many of big services doese  it! 


Secondary, please tell me, why I couldn't use hashing functions to encrypt password? Maybe you know the easy way to decrypt it? :)

Comment: @domino if you type a trim intentionally, and i trim it for one more time, then you don't notice it.